# divs allignment

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align these divs next to each other but only the first two divs are aligned.
Anyone knows what i have to do?

```
  <div id="user-tweets" style="float:left; width:25%; border:solid #FCF 1px; height:300px;"></div>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="float:left; width:45%; border:solid #FCF 1px; height:400px"></div>
  <div id="news-tweets" style"float:left; width:20%; border:solid #0056A3 5px; height:500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you were missing an `=` on the third item.

http://jsfiddle.net/dP9uK/

```
<div id="user-tweets" style="float:left; width:25%; border:solid #FCF 1px; height:300px;"></div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="float:left; width:45%; border:solid #FCF 1px; height:400px"></div>
<div id="news-tweets" style="float:left; width:20%; border:solid #0056A3 5px; height:500px;"></div>​
```

Comment: @BillyMoat it's not my question. I just commented.

Comment: @BillyMoat There is a timer until people can accept an answer ;) 15 minutes I believe.

Comment: @yunzen - Sorry, still half sleeping I think.

Comment: @BillyMoat  It's the early bird that catches the worm. :)